# Value of property Targets must be a list of objects"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup"error

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Below is the code i have using in my cloud formation network load balancer template , can you please help me on this

```
"TargetGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "MyTargets",
                "Port": 10,
                "TargetType": "instance",
                "Protocol": "TCP",
                "TargetGroupAttributes": [{
                    "Key": "deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds",
                    "Value": "20"
                }],
                "VpcId": {
                    "Fn::Select": [
                        "0",
                        {
                            "Ref": "VPC"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Targets": [ "Id", {"Ref": "Id.ins1"    },  "Id", {"Ref": "Id.ins2"}    ]
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value for Targets. Targets should be a list of TargetDescription. Syntax for TargetDescription:

```
{
  "AvailabilityZone" : String,
  "Id" : String,
  "Port" : Integer
}
```

In your case it will be something like this:

```
"Targets":[ { "Id":{ "Ref":"Id.ins1" },"Port":80 },{ "Id":{ "Ref":"Id.ins2" },"Port":80 } ]
```